# How to group neighbour-siblings

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i have something like this:

```
<root>
  <a>foo</a>
  <b>bar</b>
  <groupme>foobar</groupme>
  <groupme>baz</groupme>
  <groupme>42</groupme>
  <c>abc</c>
  <d>def</d>
  <groupme>foo</groupme>
  <x>xyz</x>
  <groupme>bar</groupme>
  <groupme>foo</groupme>
  <z>thats it</z>
</root>
```

now i need all groume's which are direct neighbours to be a single node like:

```
<root>
  <a>foo</a>
  <b>bar</b>
  <groupme>foobar baz 42</groupme>
  <c>abc</c>
  <d>def</d>
  <groupme>foo</groupme>
  <x>xyz</x>
  <groupme>bar foo</groupme>
  <z>thats it</z>
</root>
```

also the groupme nodes containing other nodes, i've just leave them to provide a simple example.
the groupme nodes only apear in a specific level, no groupme nodes in others then root.

any help for me?

Comment: Dirk, does the posted code help solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Such grouping can be achieved with an approach called "sibling recursion", for your problem I would suggest a stylesheet as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/groupme[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme])]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::groupme][1]" mode="list"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/groupme[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme]]"/>


<xsl:template match="root/groupme[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme]]" mode="list">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][self::groupme][1]" mode="list"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input

```
<root>
  <a>foo</a>
  <b>bar</b>
  <groupme>foobar</groupme>
  <groupme>baz</groupme>
  <groupme>42</groupme>
  <c>abc</c>
  <d>def</d>
  <groupme>foo</groupme>
  <x>xyz</x>
  <groupme>bar</groupme>
  <groupme>foo</groupme>
  <z>thats it</z>
</root>
```

the result is

```
<root>
  <a>foo</a>
  <b>bar</b>
  <groupme>foobar baz 42</groupme>
  <c>abc</c>
  <d>def</d>
  <groupme>foo</groupme>
  <x>xyz</x>
  <groupme>bar foo</groupme>
  <z>thats it</z>
</root>
```

As an alternative to the sibling recursion it is also possible to "grab" the following siblings with a key based approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key 
  name="first"
  match="root/groupme[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme]]"
  use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::groupme[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme])][1])"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/groupme[not(preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme])]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('first', generate-id())" mode="list"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/groupme[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::groupme]]"/>

<xsl:template match="root/groupme" mode="list">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```